# Rails: Getting an ActiveRecord collection instead of Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Shop model which has many users:

Shop.rb

```
 def active_users
    users.where(status: "active").reverse
  end
```

Currently, when I call some_shop.active_users, I get an array of user objects. But is it possible to instead get an ActiveRecord collection of Users?

Comment: It is turning into an array because you are calling the ``reverse`` method on it, which is an array method. Reverse is wrong here anyway as you can never be sure about the order in which db returns values unless you call ``order`` instead, which turns into an ``order by`` in the sql statement. because ``order`` is an active record method, the output of it will not be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lazy binding. It'll be an array when you access it.
Try it by calling `active_users.to_a`

Comment: Is there a way to keep it, or change it to an ActiveRecord collection?

Comment: I'm trying to use a paginate method which only works on collections.

Comment: This is how ActiveRecord is designed. What is exactly not working for you? The pagination will work with it.

Comment: This works for me: users = current_shop.users.page(params[:page]).per(10)

Comment: But this does not work: users = current_shop.active_users.page(params[:page]).per(10)

Comment: users is an AR relation. but active_users is a shop method to return Users.where(status: "active")

Comment: When I call  current_shop.active_users.page  I get "undefined method page for Array"

Comment: That's because pagination works on an ActiveRecord and not an array. You can't do a reverse that way. You need to use ActiveRecord to reorder the list which will result in a database query with an ordering parameter (like ORDER BY in SQL)

Comment: So is there a way I could paginate "active users"  instead of all users? I don't want to show all users in the view.

Comment: Yes, just remove a ```reverse```. If you need to reverse that list then you need to use ActiveRecord way of reversing, which is via SQL's ```ORDER BY```